# Web page larger than body height?

Tags: css, height, html

This webpage being in beta, http://porkystuff.com, has a very big problem.
The webpage is larger than the BODY and the HTML tags. I've checked this with developer tools in both Chrome and Firefox.
I HAVE tried adding `html, body{ height:100%; }`.

Comment: the problem is your hight in .sidecontent. change it from 150% to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Got it!! in your CSS a class name sidecontent height is 150%.

```
.sidecontent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150%;
left: 820px;
top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i just needed to stretch the `body` and `html` tag to full-page size by these CSS tricks:

```
html {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

reference link : https://makandracards.com/makandra/39473-stretching-an-html-page-to-full-height